# Bootstrap 3 tooltip arrow does not display properly with multiline message

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have a link with a tooltip on it. The tooltip message is a bit long so it's displayed on two lines.

```html
<a href="/link/1234" class="tooltips" title="See the comment">Comment</a>
```

My problem is that the arrow of the tooltip is displayed on the middle of the tooltip, not at its bottom (see the screenshot)

[image: the tooltip with its problematic arrow]

Additional information:

- the link is in a table cell
- I toggle the tooltips with `$('.tooltips').tooltip({container: 'body'});`

How can I do to fix this arrow?

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the tag attributes?, it's necessary render the tooltip arrow position

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>
```

just apply it in a tag:

```
<a href="/link/1234" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" class="tooltips" title="See the comment">Comment</a>
```

[Bootstrap 3 tooltip's doc reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tooltips)